# R download package CentOS 6

Tags: r, hadoop, centos6

I am trying to download packages with R and nothing is happening.
I tried to change the proxy.
I tried to change the mirror.
I tried that : `setInternet2(use = TRUE)` in `.libPaths()`

I don't know what else I can do.

I'm working on a Hadoop distribution (CentOS 6) and I installed RStudio Server.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is happening"? I would be surprised there is any message. What command do you use?

Comment: I'm using install.packages("functional"). The warning message is  Warning messages:
1: In open.connection(con, "r") :
  unable to connect to 'cran.r-project.org' on port 80.
2: package ‘httr’ is not available (for R version 3.1.3)

Comment: Probably version issue ? install.packages("functional")  worked for me today Version 0.99.891 , and R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)